# .sty file missing Even that is included in other Package

Tags: packages, installing

I am writing a paper for R journal and using their [template file](https://journal.r-project.org/submissions.html). Package `environ` is added in `RJournal` package (means not included separately). But while execution there is error that `environ.sty not found`, and no other error. Please guide me how to tackle this issuse.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? MiKTeX? TeXLive? Are you using a front-end to manage your TeX installation?

Comment: @WillieWong m using MikTex. What is "front-end"?

Comment: Follow the [instructions here](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console) and start MikTeX console, go to the package tab, and install the `environ` package. // Or you can go to the Settings tab and turn on "automatic package installation".

Comment: @WillieWong but why add one more time, when it is available in RJournal pkg.

Comment: MikTeX keeps a database of filenames (dbfn).  You need to make sure Rjournal is included, or it will not be recognized.  Using the MikTeX console, use Settings->Directories to make sure the directory containing Rjornal is added.  Then use Tasks->Refresh Filename Database.

Comment: The `RJournal.sty` file does not "include" `environ`, it **requires** the package as it uses some of its functionalities. If you don't have `environ.sty` on your system, the `RJournal.sty` file cannot run. It is exactly the same thing as programming in R: if your code depends on a package on CRAN and that package is not installed locally, your code cannot run.